# Bootstrap4 плавный скролл

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

html :

```
 <style>
  .checkpoint {
    margin-top: 800px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
  }

</style>
  <header>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar'>
      <div class='container'>
        <a class="navbar-brand black-text">VegasAccademy</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type='button' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#basicExampleNav" aria-controls="basicExampleNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='basicExampleNav'>
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto smooth-scroll">
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <a  class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light' href="#intro">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <a  class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light' href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <a  class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light' href="#purpose">Purpose</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <a  class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light' href="#teachers">Teachers</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <a  class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light' href="#map">Map</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class='navbar-nav nav-flex-icons'>
          <li class='nav-item'>
            <a href="" class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light'>
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
           <li class='nav-item'>
            <a href="" class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light'>
              <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
           <li class='nav-item'>
            <a href="" class='nav-link waves-effect waves-light'>
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id='intro' class='view'>
      <div class='mask rgba-black-strong'>
        <div class='container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100'>
          <div class='row d-flex justify-content-center text-center'>
            <div class='col-md-10'>
              <h2 class='display-4 font-weight-bold white-text pt-5 mb-2'>
                Studying in EU
              </h2>
              <hr class='hr-light'>
              <h4 class='white-text my-4'>Knowledge makes one laugh, but wealth makes one dance.</h4>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-white waves-effect waves-light'>Read More <i class='fa fa-book'></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class='checkpoint' id='about'></div> 
  <div class='checkpoint' id='purpose'></div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

По неизвестной мне причине не работает плавный скрол.

Comment: В вашем примере все работает, через якорь вы попадаете на нужную часть контента, а плавным переход таким путем как делаете вы не будет!

Answer (score 0):

Для плавного скрола используйте либо Jquery:

```
var $page = $('html, body');
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
    $page.animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 400);
    return false;
});
```

Либо Javascript:

```js
// собираем все якоря; устанавливаем время анимации и количество кадров
const anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')),
      animationTime = 300,
      framesCount = 20;

anchors.forEach(function(item) {
  // каждому якорю присваиваем обработчик события
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // убираем стандартное поведение
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // для каждого якоря берем соответствующий ему элемент и определяем его координату Y
    let coordY = document.querySelector(item.getAttribute('href')).getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
    
    // запускаем интервал, в котором
    let scroller = setInterval(function() {
      // считаем на сколько скроллить за 1 такт
      let scrollBy = coordY / framesCount;
      
      // если к-во пикселей для скролла за 1 такт больше расстояния до элемента
      // и дно страницы не достигнуто
      if(scrollBy > window.pageYOffset - coordY && window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset < document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // то скроллим на к-во пикселей, которое соответствует одному такту
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollBy);
      } else {
        // иначе добираемся до элемента и выходим из интервала
        window.scrollTo(0, coordY);
        clearInterval(scroller);
      }
    // время интервала равняется частному от времени анимации и к-ва кадров
    }, animationTime / framesCount);
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#head1">head 1</a>
  <li><a href="#head2">head 2</a>
  <li><a href="#head3">head 3</a>
  <li><a href="#head4">head 4</a>
</ul>

<h2 id="head1">heading 1</h2>
<h2 id="head2">heading 2</h2>
<h2 id="head3">heading 3</h2>
<h2 id="head4">heading 4</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

К ответу выше. В js'е не обязательно считать время анимации и кол-во кадров. Есть уже нативные способы анимации скролла.

Javascript:

```
const headerH = document.querySelector('.header').getBoundingClientRect().height; // Если  header имеет position: fixed; то берём его высоту, чтобы скролл не перекрывал элемент на конец анимации. Если header не фиксированный, то можно его не использовать. (1)

document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let currentHref    = this.getAttribute('href'),
        currentAnchor  = document.getElementById(currentHref.substring(1)),
        currentAnchorT = currentAnchor.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    window.scrollTo({
      top: currentAnchorT - headerH + window.scrollY, // headerH не обязателен (1)
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Добавление к ответу лучше публиковать комментарием, сущность "Ответ" подразумевает не зависящее от других ответов сообщение, так сказать самоценное. Если вам необходимо добавить объёмны код - это можно сделать с помощью сервисов наподобие cpp.sh (такие есть практически для всех языков), на крайний случай что-нибудь вроде youtext.

Comment: Так и хотел сделать, но увы, могу комментировать только имея 50 баллов репутации.